# How to make a http GET request FROM a WCF web service

Tags: .net, wcf

There are tons of information about how to make a GET request TO a WCF service.
But I need to make a http GET request FROM a WCF web service to some 3rd party server that provides some service I need.
So, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the .net WebRequest object:

> ```
> public class WebRequestGetExample
>     {
>         public static void Main ()
>         {
>             // Create a request for the URL.      
>             WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
>             // If required by the server, set the credentials.
>             request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
>             // Get the response.
>             HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
>             // Display the status.
>             Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);
>             // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
>             Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
>             // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
>             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
>             // Read the content. 
>             string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
>             // Display the content.
>             Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
>             // Cleanup the streams and the response.
>             reader.Close ();
>             dataStream.Close ();
>             response.Close ();
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: This is fast. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to have a try finally block to ensure that the datastream, response are closed correctly.